# Regex get value of a specific word

Tags: c#, regex

I've got the following value:

```
--> Some comment

CREATE VIEW ABC
   AS SELECT
   Z.NUMBER                                       AS    ID,
   Z.LANGUAGE                                     AS    LNG,
   SUBSTR(Z.VALUE_01,01,02)                       AS    RUN_NUMB,
   SUBSTR(Z.TXT_VALUE_01,01,79)                   AS    TXT
   FROM
   MYTABLE Z
   WHERE     ID                  = '0033'
   AND       LNG                 = 'DE'
```

I want a regular expression, where I can pass the value (or a part of the value) before the *AS* and I'll receive the AS-Value, e.g.

Z.NUMBER --> I'll receive ID

Z.LANGUAGE --> I'll receive LNG

Z.VALUE_01 --> I'll receive RUN_NUMB

Z.TXT_VALUE_01 --> I'll receive TXT

Currently I have something like this:

```
(?<=Z.NUMBER\sAS).+?(?=(,|FROM))
```

...but this doesn't work for my *SUBSTR* values

Edit: I'm using C# to execute the Regex:

```
string expr = @"--> Some comment ....."; //so the long text
string columnExprValue = "Z.LANGUAGE";
string asValue = Regex.Match(expr, @"(?<=" + columnExprValue + @"\sAS).+?(?=(,|FROM))")?.Value.Replace("AS", "").Trim() ?? ""; //Workaround to remove AS, because I don't know how to remove it in Regex
```

Comment: Which flavour of regex are you using, or alternatively, which is the surrounding programming language (or software) in which you use it?

Comment: C# / .NET 5. I could also use split and/or Linq, but I want to do it with regex :)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.  Do you want one regex that does four different things at once?  Or four separate regex?  Do you want to convert the value of variables named or are you trying to convert the string that is the variable name into some other string?

Comment: I have the following Regex in C# `Regex.Match(expr, @"(((((?<=" + columnExprValue + @")*)).AS).+?(?=(,|FROM)))")`   
The variable expr is the long text in my question.
The variable columnExprValue is my value, like `Z.LANGUAGE` or `Z.TXT_VALUE_01`. Therefore I want a regex (with a placeholder, which is my value, which I'm passing), which returns me the value of my passed value after AS.

Comment: Be careful when *parsing* with *regular expressions*: in general case you have to put *strings*, *comments* etc. into account: create `view MyView Abc as select z.a /* as id */ as myId, 'z.b as id' as st_id, "z.c as id" c_id`. If you have to work with arbitrary sql have a look at *sql parsers*

Comment: Just to clarify, your question is about parsing a string.  The string is the value that you have displayed in the code box in your question.

Comment: @Tom yes. I have the SQL-statement and the 4 values, which start with “Z.“ ... For each “Z.“-value I want to get the value after AS using Regex. Therefore in my C# code I'd use Regex.Match(...) for every "Z."-value and receive ITS AS-value.

Comment: Try `(?<=Z\.(?:LANGUAGE|NUMBER|(?:TXT_)?VALUE_01)\b.*[\p{Zs}\t]AS[\p{Zs}\t]+)[^\s,]+` and then make the part with the values in the alternation dynamic. See https://regex101.com/r/jqEqsV/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, but the implementation is "naive" in sense that it always expects correct valid parameters that do really exists, you can add necessary checks needed.

So the regex I'm going to use is this `.*Z\.VALUE_01.*\s+AS\s+(?<Alias>[^,\s]*)`, where `"Z\.VALUE_01"` I will do as parameter. See regex tester - https://regex101.com/r/UJi8pY/1
The idea here is that in `Group` named `"Alias"` we should have the exact thing you are looking for

Then C# code will look like this:

```
public static string GetAlias(string input, string column)
{
    var regexPart = column.Replace(".","\\.");
    
    return Regex.Match(input, $".*{regexPart}.*\\s+AS\\s+(?<Alias>[^,\\s]*)").Groups["Alias"].ToString();
}
public static void Main()
{
    string val = @"--> Some comment
    CREATE VIEW ABC
    AS SELECT
    Z.NUMBER                                       AS    ID,
    Z.LANGUAGE                                     AS    LNG,
    SUBSTR(Z.VALUE_01,01,02)                       AS    RUN_NUMB,
    SUBSTR(Z.TXT_VALUE_01,01,79)                   AS    TXT
    FROM
    MYTABLE Z
    WHERE     ID                  = '0033'
    AND       LNG                 = 'DE'";
    
    Console.WriteLine(GetAlias(val, "Z.NUMBER"));
    Console.WriteLine(GetAlias(val, "Z.LANGUAGE "));
    Console.WriteLine(GetAlias(val, "Z.VALUE_01"));
    Console.WriteLine(GetAlias(val, "Z.TXT_VALUE_01"));
}
```

.NET Fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z9kd8h

Good suggestion in another answer from @the-fourth-bird to use `Regex.Escape` instead of `column.Replace(".","\\.")`, so all regex symbols would be escaped

Comment: You’re welcome, answer from @the-fourth-bird is also very good :)

Comment: Yes, I also liked his version, but in your solution the string could also be `SUBSTR(Z.TXT_VALUE_0123456789,01,79)` and your method GetAlias still returns the value `TXT` by passing `Z.TXT_VALUE_01`, which I really like. Instead of `column.Replace` I used `Regex.Escape` from the answer of @the-fourth-bird :)

Answer (score 2):

Getting the values with a regex from sql can be very brittle, this pattern is based on the example data.

To get the values only you might use lookarounds:

```
(?<=\bZ\.(?:LANGUAGE|NUMBER|(?:TXT_)?VALUE_01)\b.*?\sAS\s+)[^\s,]+(?=,|\s+FROM\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Lookbehind assertion

  - `\b` A word boundary
  - `Z\.` Match `Z.`
  - `(?:LANGUAGE|NUMBER|(?:TXT_)?VALUE_01)\b` Match any of the alternatives followed by a word boundary (Or just match a single string like `Z\.LANGUAGE`)
  - `.*?` Match optional characters, as few as possible
  - `\sAS\s+` Match `AS` between whitespace chars
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `[^\s,]+` Match 1+ non whitspace chars except for a comma
- `(?=,|\s+FROM\b)` Positive lookahead, assert either `,` or  `FROM` to the right

See a [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5crDSc/1).

Or a capture group variant:

```
\bZ\.(?:LANGUAGE|NUMBER|(?:TXT_)?VALUE_01)\b.*?\sAS\s+([^\s,])+(?:,|\s+FROM\b)
```

See another [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SbLn9i/1).

If you want to make the pattern dynamic, you can make use of [Regex.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-7.0) to escape the meta characters like the dot to match it literally, or else it would match any character.

For example:

```
string input = @"--> Some comment

CREATE VIEW ABC
AS SELECT
Z.NUMBER                                       AS    ID,
Z.LANGUAGE                                     AS    LNG,
SUBSTR(Z.VALUE_01,01,02)                       AS    RUN_NUMB,
SUBSTR(Z.TXT_VALUE_01,01,79)                   AS    TXT
FROM
MYTABLE Z
WHERE     ID                  = '0033'
AND       LNG                 = 'DE'";           
string columnExprValue = Regex.Escape("Z.LANGUAGE");
string pattern = @"(?<=\b" + columnExprValue + @"\b.*?\sAS\s+)[^\s,]+(?=,|\s+FROM\b)";
string asValue = Regex.Match(input, pattern)?.Value ?? "";
Console.WriteLine(asValue);
```

Output

```
LNG
```

Comment: I marked Nikita Chaykas answer as correct, because he answered earlier and in his version it would also work if my value would be `SUBSTR(Z.TXT_VALUE_1234,01,02)` and I look for `Z.TXT_VALUE_1`, but your answer is very helpful, too! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Rudi That is perfectly ok, glad you have found a solution that works for you. If you also want to match that usecase, you can omit the word boundary after the non capture group like this `(?<=\bZ\.(?:LANGUAGE|NUMBER|(?:TXT_)?VALUE_01).*?\sAS\s+)[^\s,]+(?=,|\s+FROM\b)` See https://regex101.com/r/ceYf4B/1

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/SCrFuf/1) :

```
/^ \h*+ (?:substr[(])?(?: Z.TXT_VALUE_01 )(?:,[^,]+,[^,]+[)])? \h* AS \h+ (\w+) \v* [,]? \v* $/gmxi
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works if there's also SUBSTR at the beginning. If there's something else, like SUBSTRING, then it doesn't work.